# Altium Schematics: what does Locked function mean?

Tags: schematics, altium

I am drawing a schematics in Altium Designer and faced this function when I double click on the components. I need to know when there is a component with different parts, ex: 4 parts. I have to assign the first part as Part 1/4 and the second part as 2/4 ... etc

Do I need to Enable the Locked function or not ? And what does it mean ?

[image]

Comment: In short: A Component may have more than one parts, for ex: LM324 has 4 op-amps inside. With the part option, you select which one to use. Now for locked: When you annotate the schematic, Altium will keep all Locked parts with your selections. For ex: A component with locked enable, lets say U?/part2 will not change to U1/part1 when you annotate schematics. It will be something like U<whatever>/part2 always.

Comment: @hoo2: This is the correct answer, you should post it as one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short

**Parts inside component**

A Component may have more than one parts, for ex: LM324 has 4 op-amps inside. With the part option, you select which one to use. Altium will create netlist for the pins with the part you have selected.

**Part locked**

Now, when you annotate the schematic, Altium not only changes the component names with ? (for ex U?), but also the parts. This may cause trouble in PCB because it effects witch pins of the part is connected to the rest of the circuit. If you select "part locked", Altium will keep all locked parts with your selections. For ex: A component with locked enable, lets say U?/**part2** will not change to U1/**part1** when you annotate schematics. It will be something like Uxx/**part2** always.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Viral - Embedded hardware's answer. The locked function also makes the component non-selectable which means a single click would not select the component. This feature comes in handy when you have overlapping components.

Comment: No! It not makes the component non-selectable... This is for the PCB editor.

Answer (score -1):

Locked function when enabled, it means components value,name,annotate cannot be modified. This function is given to prevent the accidentally changing of the any of the components in schematic.

Comment: No! The value can be changed. Name also. The ONLY think that lockes is the part. Not the name. You can see it has 2 locked boxes. One for the part and one General.